# is_a? vs respond_to?

Tags: ruby

I am working on some code which checks whether or not to unlink a file on the basis of the class:

```
File.unlink(file.path) if file.is_a? File
```

I think it would be more idiomatic to check whether the object responds to the `unlink` message:

```
File.unlink(file.path) if file.respond_to? :unlink
```

Is there any good reason to prefer the `is_a?` approach?

Comment: I love my static type checker.

Comment: can you provide some more context ? This kind of code is usually avoidable with a different OO design. I recommend that you read [Some of Avdi Grimm's talks about "confident code"](http://avdi.org/talks/confident-code-railsconf-2011/) that provide nice insights on how to code comfortably in a duck-typing environment.

Comment: +1 to the different design, that's on the cards.  The existing code does this `is_a?` hack.  I thought that perhaps `respond_to?` would be a more idiomatic approach in the interim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that on some file systems a directory is simply a File with special attributes (or to put it another way a *specialized file*), does it really matter?  Unlink it if it can be unlinked if that is what you want to do.  If it can't be unlinked, why would you bother?  And why would you care what it is?  If you care what it is, then use `is_a?`  If the inode can be unlinked, unlink it.

Comment: Assume that the codebase in question is sufficiently weird that it's possible the 'file' isn't even vaguely related to the filesystem - neither a directory or a file :-/

Comment: Then you are asking about nodes and trees?  But no, still so you care what it is, if it responds to the behavior, then simply do the behavior.

Comment: that's what I was thinking, hence the change to `respond_to?`